# AFNetworking: how to get the response string when failed?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                 parameters:(id)parameters
                    success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                    failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

to communicate with the server, and it works great.

But sometimes, there is an error on the server, and it's response is not in json format. My partner wants me to show the error string, but since it went to the failure block, I can hardly get the original response string.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may log `operation.responseString` line in success and failure block both to get response string of server.

If webservice has some kind of error and provide invalid json or response then log `[error description]` in failure block.

For reference please check below code snippet.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:120];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
[manager POST:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",URL]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] parameters:parameters 
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
     {
       NSLog(@"Response: %@", operation.responseString);  
     } 
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
     {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@ \n %@", operation.responseString,[error description]);
     }];
```

Comment: In New AFNetworking there is no AFHTTPRequestOperation in Failure block

Comment: It depends on which AFNetworking version you are using. In latest AFNetworking, It is replaced by AFHTTPSessionManager.

Answer (score 0):

In the failure block, add these codes:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
NSString *message = [userInfo objectForKey:@"message"];
```

I think message is what you need, you can use NSLog to reveal the info.

Comment: The result depends on the server, you can NSLog the error or just ask the backend partner the format.

Comment: Nothing but `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x170073780 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Comment: My  backend partner wants to see the response string to find out what's going on with the json format error.

Comment: Have you use curl to simulate the request and see the result? Only happens on AFNetworking?

Comment: Of course curl works, but it's very troublesome to write, especially when there are parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To take error code(response code) you can use `[operation.response statusCode];`

Error detail should be here

```
id responseObject = error.userInfo[kErrorResponseObjectKey];
```

Referanced from: http://www.splinter.com.au/2014/09/10/afnetworking-error-bodies/

Comment: It not works. responseObject is null. The response code is 200, but it's not in json format.

Comment: `NSString *urlStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"];
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
        [manager GET:urlStr parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) `

Comment: {
            NSLog(@"responseObject: %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
            NSString *message = [userInfo objectForKey:@"message"];
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
            NSLog(@"message: %@", message);
            
            id responseObject = error.userInfo[kErrorResponseObjectKey];
            NSLog(@"responseObject: %@", responseObject);
        }];

Comment: The log: `2015-03-12 18:04:05.544 AFNetworking iOS Example[37233:60b] error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x17007fd40 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
2015-03-12 18:04:05.545 AFNetworking iOS Example[37233:60b] message: (null)
2015-03-12 18:04:05.545 AFNetworking iOS Example[37233:60b] responseObject: (null)`

Comment: I need the original response string from server.

Comment: are you expecting json format? i guess you are taking login page redirection error. So it returns 200 but response is not json. as mentioned above can you check "operation.responseString" ? But if it is also not a redirection error, i suggest you to handle server response if it couldn't create json (make this on server, not on client)

Comment: add manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]; too